# Android getLocationOnScreen problem: wrong coordinates

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, coordinates

I've got problem with getting coordinates of view. I've got three custom views placed in LinearLayout. When I touch any of them I've got wrong coordinates. For example second view is placed in the center, but getLocationOnScreen() returns x = 0. This is impossible.
And this coordinates always differs from values that i can get through event.getX() and event.getY().

Please, could you tell me, what is the problem?

Results (through Log.w)

First view: onTouch_coords: 0, 50

Second view: onTouch_coords: 0, 98

Third view: onTouch_coords: 0, 146

This is gui xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.remaller.android.DragAndDropBasicsInheriting.DragableView  
        android:id="@+id/DragableView1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <com.remaller.android.DragAndDropBasicsInheriting.DragableView  
        android:id="@+id/DragableView2" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <com.remaller.android.DragAndDropBasicsInheriting.DragableView  
        android:id="@+id/DragableView3" 
        android:src = "@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is source code for my DragableView:

```
    public class DragableView extends ImageView
{
    private void init()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        int action = event.getAction();

        int this_coords[] = {0,0};
        this.getLocationOnScreen(this_coords);

        Log.w("daxh","onTouch_coords: "+this_coords[0]+", "+this_coords[1]);

        switch(action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            default:

            break;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public DragableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public DragableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DragableView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
}
```

This is the code for activity:

```
   public class DragAndDropBasicsInheritingActivity extends Activity
{
    public static final int CREATE = 0x00000001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.draganddropbasicsinheritingactivity_gui);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.getLocationOnScreen(this_coords);`it always returns the location of `this`View, a.k.a `DragableView` . [method specification here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29).

As this View is your main view, it would definitely show `x=0`

`event.getX()` gave you the coordinate x of where your performed the event like touch,drag...

That's two different methods to two Objects.